# Ambiguïté sur l'agent dans une construction infinitive

Tags: infinitif, sujet

> Paul a proposé à Pierre de venir.

Comment peut-on savoir si le sujet de venir est Paul ou Pierre ?

Comment: Selon les commentaires il semble qu'il soit préférable de considérer la phrase sur un plan non grammatical et au lieu de parler de sujet de demander laquelle des deux personnes doit venir selon le sens; Les grammairiens ne sont pas d'accord sur les caractères propres de la proposition infinitive. L'infinitif doit avoir son sujet propre.https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_infinitive#Proposition_infinitive_subordonnée

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il n'y a pas le moindre indice dans la phrase qui permette de décider duquel il s'agit; de telles phrases ne sont plus un problème lorsqu'un contexte situe clairement que l'un ou l'autre est l'agent en puissance de l'action; autrement c'est de la responsabilité de celui qui parle ou écrit d'utiliser une construction non ambigüe.

Comment: Hmmm... le ***sujet*** de *venir* n'est pas ou Paul ou Pierre. Le sujet de **venir** n'est **ni** Paul **ni** Pierre. *venir* est ici utilisé à l'infinitif et un infinitif n'a pas de sujet.

Comment: @aCOSwt Voilà ce que je tire de la simple petite grammaire de Wikipédia : Ainsi, dans : « Hélène voit sa mère venir » : dans la proposition principale le sujet (qui voit) est Hélène, dans la proposition subordonnée le sujet (qui est-ce qui vient) est sa mère. Qu'est-ce vous voudriez dire par « pas de sujet »?

Comment: @aCoSwt Oui, je vois; « Paul » autant que l'on s'en tient strictement à des principes de grammaire ne peut être que le sujet de « proposer »; c'est ce à quoi vous voudriez en venir, je suppose.

Comment: Ta correction (sujet->agent) montre que tu as compris. Il ne peut exister qu'une sorte de *sujet* : le sujet **syntaxique**. Et un infinitif ne connaît pas ce truc. On peut évidemment vouloir parler d'une sorte de *sujet **sémantique*** mais alors on suit Riegel et on ne parle plus de **sujet** mais d'*agent, de locatif, de cause...* À noter que là encore, c'est le **verbe** qui assigne ce rôle à son premier actant et ici, en particulier, le premier actant... est aussi inconnu. Bref, pour *venir*, ici... pas de sujet.. du tout. La définition du sujet en tant que celui qui fait l'action a vécu.